# search form is not taking the entire width of the screen bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an form tag for search function with input and a button. If I place the form on a plain html, the input type and the button spans across the width of the div but if I embed it into the div I am working with, it shrinks to the left. This is the snippet

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="min-height:280px">

             <div style="margin-bottom:18px; clear:both;" class="row">

                            <div class="col-lg-7"  >
                          <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post"
                          action="/grantaccess">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="searchName" type="email" class="form-control search-form" placeholder="Search">
                           <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                        </form></div>

                        </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body"> 


                                          <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                                    RETRIEVED DETAILS
                                                </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                              <div class="container">
```

Please how can I make the form span across the width of the div

Comment: The input is wide like the div is. So, you want to make it full-width, use the class .col-lg-12 (for example, bootstrap default). If its not you want to do, please add a fiddle to let us understand better.

Comment: did not work.....

Comment: Then please, add a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio for your IDE, check your site.css and see if you have the following css:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

I believe this is added by default to new MVC web projects.  Comment it out and your input fields will go to 100% width.